# Mapping arbitrary length list to fixed length, preserving frequency and position of internal results (as much as possible)

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

BACKSTORY:

Getting data together to feed into a neural network; starts as a document (long string); gets split into sentences, sentences are reduced to 1 or 0 depending on if they have a feature (in this case, class of word) or not.

The catch is that documents have different numbers of sentences, so it can't be a 1-1 between sentences and input neurons; you have to train to a fixed number of neurons (unless I'm missing something).

So, I'm working on an algo to map arrays to a fixed size, while preserving the frequency and position of those 1's in the array as much as possible (as that's what the NN is making its decisions off of.

CODE:

say we're aiming for a fixed length of 10 sentences or neurons, and need to be able to handle arrays of smaller and larger size.

```
new_length = 10
short = [1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
long  = [1,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1]

def map_to_fixed_length(arr, new_length):
    arr_length = len(arr)
    partition_size = arr_length/new_length
    res = []
    for i in range(new_length):
        slice_start_index = int(math.floor(i * partition_size))
        slice_end_index = int(math.ceil(i * partition_size))
        partition = arr[slice_start_index:slice_end_index]
        val = sum(partition)
        res.append([slice_start_index, slice_end_index, partition])
        if val > 0:
            res.append(1)
        else:
            res.append(0)
    return res
```

Not very pythonic probably. Anyways, the issue is that this is ommits certain index-slices. For example, the last index of `short` is omitted, and due to the rounding various indexes get omitted as well.

This is a simplified version of what I've been working on, which is mainly just adding if-statements to address all the gaps this leaves. But is there a better way to do this? Something a bit more statistically sound?

I was looking through numpy but all the resize functions are just padding with zeros or something pretty arbitrarily.

Comment: What's the desired output for these inputs?

Comment: It's a little variable, frankly. Current criteria are 1) correct length (obviously), 2) no missed matches (aka, err towards over-representing 1's in source vs omitting them).

Comment: If I understand what you're going for in your current code, `map_to_fixed_length([0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], 3)` should be `[1, 1, 1]`. Does that seem fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way might be to use `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` like so:

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

>>> def resample(data, n):
...     m = len(data)
...     xin, xout = np.arange(n, 2*m*n, 2*n), np.arange(m, 2*m*n, 2*m)
...     return interp1d(xin, data, 'nearest', fill_value='extrapolate')(xout)
... 
>>> resample(short, new_length)
array([1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
>>> 
>>> resample(long, new_length)
array([1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 1.])
```

Comment: Brilliant! Looks perfect. Interpolation is exactly what I was looking for, apparently. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A followup- Once the network was up and running, I tested Paul Panzer's answer vs the best I could come up with (below)

```
def resample(arr, new_length):
    arr_length = len(arr)
    partition_size = arr_length/new_length
    res = []
    last_round_end_slice = 0
    for i in range(new_length):
        slice_start_index = int(math.floor(i * partition_size))
        slice_end_index = int(math.ceil(i * partition_size))
        if slice_start_index > last_round_end_slice:
            slice_start_index = last_round_end_slice
        if i == 0:
            slice_end_index = int(math.ceil(partition_size))
        if i == new_length:
            slice_end_index = arr_length
        partition = arr[slice_start_index:slice_end_index]
        val = sum(partition)
        if val > 0:
            res.append(1)
        else:
            res.append(0)
        last_round_end_slice = slice_end_index
    return res
```

Ugly as hell, but it does work.

Average accuracy results after 1000 training cycles (full optomization cycles, all batches) were

0.9765427094697953 for mine
0.968362500667572 for scipy

Interpolation is the correct answer, but in this use case it seems a roll-your-own is a bit better. The catch with interpolation is it sometimes results in arrays that are all 0; that is, it doesn't err towards representing matches vs eliminating them.

And I suppose the ultimate requirement is consistency. So long as the input is consistently determined, the network can learn from it.

Thought that was interesting in case anyone ends up stumbling upon this